# What is the equivalent of isWindowsServer API for VS 2008 compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

In our product compiled with VS 2017 compiler we are using the IsWindowsServer API to check if the code is running in a server version OS and then take some action. For some reason, I need to import this logic to an older version of our product which runs on VS 2008 compiler. The IsWindowsServer API cannot be used here and gives error error C3861: 'strtof': identifier not found. So what is the equivalent API I can use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IsWindowsServer isn't an API per se. It's really a macro defined in `<versionhelpers.h>` that wraps [VerifyVersionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-verifyversioninfow).  This is the implementation:

```
#include <windows.h>

bool IsWindowsServer()
{
    OSVERSIONINFOEXW osvi = { sizeof(osvi), 0, 0, 0, 0, {0}, 0, 0, 0, VER_NT_WORKSTATION };
    DWORDLONG        const dwlConditionMask = VerSetConditionMask( 0, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, VER_EQUAL );

    return !VerifyVersionInfoW(&osvi, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, dwlConditionMask);
}
```

The two dependent APIs VerSetConditionMask and VerifyVersionInfo should be available in the SDK that's bundled with VS2008.